# Introducir tabuladores en un fichero despues de uniq [Linux]

Tags: linux, script

Necesito generar un informe de procesos que fallan en un día concreto de manera que tengo un archivo que he generado con un paste después de unir dos diferentes. El problema es que necesito sacar un contador para saber si hay varios que hayan fallado el mismo día y para eso uso el `uniq -c` hasta ahí todo bien. 
Consigo lo siguiente:

> 1 EF63024D     20190930
>   1 EF63024M     20190919
>   2 EF63O020     20190904
>   2 EF63O020     20190905
>   1 EF63O020     20190906
>   2 EF63O020     20190910
>   3 EF63O020     20190911
>   4 EF63O020     20190912
>   2 EF63O020     20190916

He logrado meterle un tabulador entre el nombre y la fecha mediante el paste. Pero entre el numero de contador y el nombre del proceso no soy capaz ni con un `unexpand -t1` ni con `unexpand -a`  porque lo que hay en el medio no es un espacio (no sé que es, pero un espacio no es) lo metí en el notepad++ y parece un blanco pero no sé como referirme esa "cosa" para sustituirla.

Comment: cat - A fichero   muestra todos los caracteres no imprimibles. Quizás te sea de ayuda para identificar esa "cosa".

Comment: ¿Aún tienes esta problema? Con `awk` podría hacerse fácil

Answer (score 0):

Considera usar `sed` para sustituir la "cosa" (interpretada aquí como cualquier caracter no alfanumérico) por un tabulador.

```bash
sed 's/[^[:alnum:]]/\t/g' <entrada.txt >salida.txt
```

Comment: Considera explicar que es `sed` y cómo se usa. Hazla publicidad al `sed`.

Comment: Gracias @CandidMoe, sugiero consultar el [tutorial Sed](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) de _Bruce Barnett_.